# PyStan: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class ‘int’>

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, bayesian, stan

I'm using PyStan in a Jupyter notebook. This is possible with the `nest_asyncio.apply()` trick. Stan seems to have some issue receiving a numpy array of integer variables.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import stan 
import nest_asyncio 
nest_asyncio.apply()

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

treatment_slope = 0.2
test_slope = 0.15
intercept = 0.7

def link(X):
    theta = sigmoid(X[0] * treatment_slope + X[1] * test_slope + intercept)
    return theta

ctrl = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=link([0,0]), size=500)
test_no_exp = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=link([0,1]), size=250)
test_w_exp = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=link([0,1]), size=250)

import pandas as pd 
data = {'test':[], 'exposure':[], 'outcome':[]}
for c in ctrl:
    data['test'].append(0)
    data['exposure'].append(0)
    data['outcome'].append(c)
    
for t in test_no_exp:
    data['test'].append(1)
    data['exposure'].append(0)
    data['outcome'].append(t)
    
for e in test_w_exp:
    data['test'].append(1)
    data['exposure'].append(1)
    data['outcome'].append(e)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)    
X = df[['test','exposure']].to_numpy()
y = df['outcome']

payload = {'X':X, 'y':y, 'K':1000, 'N':2}



logistic_regression_model = """
// logistic regression code
data {
    int<lower=0> N;                 // number of observations
    int<lower=0> K;                 // number of predictor variables
    matrix[N, K] X;                 // predictor matrix
    int<lower=0,upper=1> y[N];      // outcome vector
}

parameters {
    real alpha;                     // intercept
    vector[K] theta;                // coefficients on Q_ast
    real<lower=0> sigma;            // error scale
}  

model {
    // priors
    for (d in 1:D) {
        theta[d] ~ normal(0, 1);
    }
    alpha ~ normal(0, 10);
    // likelihood
    y ~ bernoulli_logit(X * theta + alpha);
}
"""
posterior = stan.build(logistic_regression_model, data=payload)
fit = posterior.sample(num_chains=4, num_samples=1000)
```

The error returned is: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`. But my inputs, as you can reproduce from code block, are already integer types. What's the issue here?

Comment: Try `y = df['outcome'].to_numpy()`

Comment: or `y = df['outcome'].values`